# Get node value using XML::XPath module in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I m using the code below to get value of node from a XML file:

```
use XML::XPath;
use XML::XPath::XMLParser;

my $pt1 = XML::XPath->new(filename => 'test1.xml');

my $nodeset = $pt1->find('/file1/table/tname'); 

foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) 
{
   print $node->getNodeValue."\n";
}
```

**The content of 'test1.xml' is as below:**

```
<file1>
    <table>
        <tname>_sys_ident</tname>
        <ttype>regular</ttype>
        <col>
            <name>_sys_ident_asp</name>
            <type>varchar(16)</type>
            <fkey>_sys_asp</fkey>
            <attr>PRIMARY KEY</attr>
        </col>
    </table>
</file1>
```

I want to print the value of **tname**(i.e. **_sys_ident**).
But the above code in not printing anything.

If I use the following inside for loop:

```
print XML::XPath::XMLParser::as_string($node);
```

then, it gives following output:

```
<tname>_sys_ident_asp</tname>
```

I don't want this complete node name and value string. **I just want node value.**
This is the first time I am trying XML and XPath. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getNodeValue` is for [attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::Node::Attribute) nodes.  For [elements](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::Node::Element), you want the `string_value` method:

```
foreach my $node ($nodeset->get_nodelist) 
{
   print $node->string_value."\n";
}
```

Comment: What does `$nodeset->get_nodelist` do?

Comment: @alex, [read the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::NodeSet#get_nodelist())

Comment: @cjm Thanks!  FYI - I did read the docs.  Documentation is not always laid out in a way where it's easy for the end-user to find answers to all of their questions.  I expected an explanation [here in the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), where the first example of `$nodeset->get_nodelist` usage is, but there was nothing there, hence the question.  There was, similarly, no explanation of `get_nodelist` in your answer or its links.  For future readers: `get_nodelist` returns a list of nodes, whose format is described [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath::XMLParser).

Answer (score 1):

For your xpath, try /file1/table/tname/text()

Comment: Doing this, you are prompted to enter a 'function'.. (entering anything here makes the xpath command execute that instead and you have to restart your bash session to get the 'real' xpath command back)